# SOAP Service call using Google Apps Scripts produces error

Tags: soap, google-apps-script

I'm currently using Google Apps Scripts to call a simple SOAP service call. However, I keep getting an error. Does anyone have an example I could use or possibly see what's wrong with my code? My code is below:

```
function onOpen()
{


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var myValue = Browser.inputBox("Enter an IP address to trace:"); 

      var b1Range = sheet.getRange("B1");
      b1Range.setValue(myValue);

      determineCountryFromIP(myValue);


}



function determineCountryFromIP(ipAddress) {

        var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?  wsdl");
        var geoService = wsdl.getGeoIPService();

        var param = Xml.element("GetGeoIP", [
                      Xml.attribute("xmlns", "http://www.webservicex.net"),
                      Xml.element("IPAddress", [
                        ipAddress
                      ])
                    ]);

        var result = geoService.GetGeoIP(param);
        return result.Envelope.Body.GetGeoIPResponse.GetGeoIPResult.CountryCode.Text;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo in the wsdl url in your code:

> var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?  wsdl");

should be:

> var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl");